# socket.io not increasing variable jquery

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm started to learning socket.io and I have a question why my variable `newUser` not increasing every new connect ? It stays the same: 1

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
  var newUser = 0;
  newUser = newUser + 1;
  console.log(newUser);
});
```

Comment: try `connection`, also `var newUser = 0;` is going to set it to 0 isn't it

Comment: Declare var newUser = 0 outside of socket.on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `connect` callback is called every time a new connection is coming, so you always re-declare the `newUser = 0` every new connection.

You can change it by moving `newUser` to outer scope

```
var newUser = 0;
socket.on('connect', function(){
  newUser = newUser + 1;
  console.log(newUser);
});
```